# Take data from a CSV file, then compare based on the different days listed

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file ([songs.csv](http://1drv.ms/1hKw3uP)) which lists songs in the order that they were played on a radio station. Songs are listed each time they are played, so there are some duplicates each day.

What I want to do is break this up into days, find new songs played since the previous day.

For example, songs played on Monday, Tuesday would have mostly the same songs played, but some songs new songs that weren't played on Monday.

Can I use PowerShell to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this does it, but with caveats:

1. Edit the CSV file and add a top line for column names, e.g. `Date, Time, Artist, Song`
2. Delete the thousands of empty lines at the end of the file that are just `,,,`

This script will import the modified CSV, group the songs by day, then show songs played that day that weren't played the previous one day.

NB. If a song is played on Monday it will show as a new song. If it is not played on Tuesday, then is played on Wednesday it will show as a new song again since Tuesday.

NB. Because you mention songs played in order, if "Demon" is played as a new song, then is played again later the same day, it's shown again as a new song. The output is in order-played, not alphabetical-order, with no attempt to remove duplicates.

NB. There are errors in the input - spacing/spelling errors, putting the artist name in the song title column, this script takes the errors and produces errors in the output. It's not magic(tm).

```
$songs = Import-Csv .\songs.csv

$songsByDay = ($songs | Group-Object "Date" | Sort-Object -Property "Name")

$previousDay = @()
foreach ($day in $songsByDay) {
    write "----"
    write $day.Name
    $daySongTitles = @($day.Group | %{ $_.Song })

    foreach ($songTitle in $daySongTitles) {
        if ($songTitle -notin $previousDay) {
            write $songTitle
        }
    }
    $previousDay = $($daySongTitles | Sort-Object)
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed script to track songs for every day, and print the artist name, here:

```
$songs = Import-Csv .\songs.csv

$songsByDay = ($songs | Group-Object "Date" | Sort-Object -Property "Name")

$previousDay = @()
foreach ($day in $songsByDay) {
    write "----"
    write $day.Name

    foreach ($song in @($day.Group)) {

        if ($song.Song -notin $previousDay) {
            write "$($song.Artist) - $($song.Song)"
        }
    }
    $previousDay += @($day.Group | %{ $_.Song })
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic thank you, looks like it will work very well. Is there anyway to modify the script a tiny bit. Rather than checking the previous day only, can we make it checks all previous days? Also, can i please output the Artist as well as the Song name? e.g. so the output would be like (Artist - Title) instead of just the title.

Comment: @user3444441 edited my answer with an updated version.

Comment: One more modification, how can have the output of this go to an HTML file?

Comment: @user3444441 Not sure; it either needs rebuilding completely differently to use `ConvertTo-HTML`, or more likely writing HTML fragments to a file yourself, e.g. making it more like `write "<tr><td>$song.Artist</td>..." >> output.html`

Comment: I have been trying to work out, where you declare the variable $previousDay, or is this a global variable?

Comment: @user3444441 here `$previousDay = @()` this makes it an empty array.

Comment: How does the script know that $previousDay is the actual previous day or all previous days from the current day?

Comment: @user3444441 `$previousDay` starts as an empty container. The `foreach` loop runs once for each day of songs played. Inside the loop, the songs for that day are checked against the contents of the `$previousDay` container. At the end of the loop, the $previousDay container is updated, ready for the next loop, with the songs for the day - in one version it's overwritten time so it only ever has one day of songs for the next loop, in the other version it's added to so each day it gets bigger and bigger. The difference is `$previousDay =` (replace it) vs ` $previousDay +=` (add to it).

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple to do in Excel.

Firstly, you would need to ensure that you have your days in it's own column.

For example:

```
A1              B1      C1         D1        E1             F1      G1              H1
Date            Time    Artist     Song     Date            Time    Artist          Song
21/03/2014      11:26   Pharrell   Happy    20/03/2014  23:54   Clean Bandit    Rather Be
```

Now in I1, have this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(H1,D1:D94,1,FALSE)
```

Any #N/A in your H column will be a new song played that day!

For more days, you can have the next day songs starting from the next column (J) and then use the formula between 2nd day and 3rd day.